# BIOS does not boot. Integrated graphics disabled without installing other GP

Tags: firmware, reset

My motherboard is Gigabyte B75m-D3H. I accidentally disabled Onboard Graphics in BIOS settings without installing any other GPU (I don't have one). How to re-enable it? No video output is being sent from the PC either from HDMI or VGA. I only hear fan sound when I switch on the pc.

I tried holding the power button for 1 min after disconnecting all the cables. But it was of no use.

I also want to delete my nvram as many duplicate firmwares were created. This is not working for me - https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc749510%28v=ws.10%29.aspx

Comment: Try removing the CMOS battery.  You should be more careful in the future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Ramhound stated, you can try removing the CMOS battery.

Also, on most mainboards there are pins to restore bios defaults. You'll have to set a jumper on these, start your PC and the default settings will be restored.

You can find the manual here: http://download.gigabyte.eu/FileList/Manual/mb_manual_ga-b75m-d3h_e.pdf

On page 14, you will find a sketch of the mainboard layout, there you will find number 16, "CLR_CMOS".

Comment: Will that also delete my nvram?

Comment: Yes, I think so. (That's the whole purspse, because your settings are stored there and we are erase the settings so they go back to default...)